# Transform XML fields to key/value pairs in PI XSLT mapping

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, sap-pi, sap-xi

In SAP PI, I have xml files from rest services (web configurator) for which the fields can vary based on the product. For instance product A has a color, a height and a width, and product B has a color, a height, a width and a depth.

Example of incoming XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order>
    <Products>
        <Product> 
            <Color>Black</Color>
            <Height>2000</Height>
            <Width>1000</Width>
        </Product>
    </Products>
</Order>
```

To handle these varying elements, I want to convert the fields to some kind of key / value pair structure with an XSL 1.0 transformation.

Example of what I'd like to obtain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order>
    <Products>
        <Product> 
            <Var>
                <VarName>Color</VarName>
                <VarValue>Black</VarValue>
            </Var>
            <Var>
                <VarName>Height</VarName>
                <VarValue>2000</VarValue>
            </Var>
            <Var>
                <VarName>Width</VarName>
                <VarValue>1000</VarValue>
            </Var>
        </Product>
    </Products>
</Order>
```

NB: this article describes the other way around:
[XSLT: Convert Name/Value pair and transform an XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502687/xslt-convert-name-value-pair-and-transform-an-xml).

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this? It's a rather trivial task, using `<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>` to get "key" value.

Comment: Well, write a template `match="Product/*"` and inside create your structure literally as `<Var><VarName><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></VarName><VarValue><xsl:value-of select="."/></VarValue></Var>`. Handle the rest by the identity transformation template.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking such a basic question guys. xsl is not something I use very often and I thought at first the key/value thing was more complex. I really appreciate your help and comments, thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Martin told you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Product/*">
    <Var>
      <VarName>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      </VarName>
      <VarValue>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </VarValue>
    </Var>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Products">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="Product">
                <Product>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                        <Var>
                            <VarName><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></VarName>
                            <VarValue><xsl:value-of select="."/></VarValue>
                        </Var>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Product>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```